# Flutter build error: Compilation failed; how can I fix it?

Tags: flutter

Flutter error when building app

> error: method getParcelableArrayList in class Bundle cannot be applied to given types;
> return bundle.getParcelableArrayList("selectedItems", Parcelable.class);

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':file_picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

when i shanged sdk version to 19, appeared new error with another plugin, when need min 21 sdk

Comment: Then change your min sdk version to 21 and compile again. Maybe it's a different package which needs minSdkVersion to be 21

Comment: I already have the min sdk version 21